# Получение нескольких ответов от сервера, php+ajax js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, асинхронность

Возникла ситуация, в которой должно происходить следующее:

клиент отправил форму **=>** данные отправлены на сервер **=>** ответ сервера 1 **=>** ответ сервера 2 **=>**...**=>** ответ сервера, что работа завершена и закрытие скрипта на клиенте.

Гугл сказал, что надо использовать long-polling. Взял за основу [эту реализацию](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/how-do-i-implement-basic-long-polling). Немного изменив получил:

`script.js`

```
function hear(formData, i = 1)
{
    formData.append('i', i);
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        url: '/handler.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formData,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        timeout:50000,
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert(data.result);// ответы
            if(data.result != null)
            {
                i++;
                setTimeout(hear(formData, i), 1000);
            }
            else alert('Запрос окончен');
        }
    });
};

$("form").submit(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var formData = new FormData(element[0]);
    var error = false;
    hear(formData);
    return false;
});
```

`handler.php`

```
<?php
    $i = $_POST['i'];
//что-то делает
    if($i == 1) echo json_encode( array('result'=>'Первый ответ') );
//что-то делает
    if($i == 2) echo json_encode( array('result'=>'Второй ответ') );
//что-то делает
    if($i == 3) echo json_encode( array('result'=>null) );
?>
```

Ответы отсылаются, ура. НО: во-первых, куча if - это плохо; а во-вторых, что более важно: php получает запрос, обрабатывает его и умирает. А здесь я просто отправляю форму три раза и это глупо. То, чего я хотел добиться, не вышло.

Дальше гугл меня направил в сторону Server-Sent Events (SSE), WebSockets, Multipart XMLHTTPRequest (только для Firefox?), XMLHTTPRequest: Interactive. (Взято [отсюда](https://habrahabr.ru/post/120429/))

**Вопрос:** Какую технологию целесообразнее использовать для такой, вроде бы, легкой задачи? Веб-сокеты, как мне кажется, точно будут избыточны. Но также мне что-то подсказывает, что на js ajax без костылей это тоже не выйдет. Хотя я очень надеюсь, что ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 0):

ну, если надо по-быстрому - лично я бы "в лоб" решал.

клиент - первый запрос

сервер - ответ "ок, запрос принят",

клиент (по первому ответу) уходит в цикл, и раз в Х секунд спрашивает сервер "ну что там?"

сервер отвечает "ничего, ждем" (тогда клиент продолжает цикл) или "первый этап готов" (тогда клиент как-то реагирует на прохождение первого этапа, и снова уходит в цикл, но уже ждет второго этапа),

и т.п.

только для этого на сервере долгоиграющий процесс-обработчик должен где-то (в БД, например, или в сессии) оставлять инфу о ходе выполнения запроса (например, статус обработки), а скрипт, который принимает запросы "Ну что там" - просто смотрит на статус и говорит "сейчас этап такой-то".

ну и если по уму, то скрипт, который принимает первый (инициирующий) запрос - должен не сам его обрабатывать, а в очередь поставить и сохранить статус "еще ничего не делалось", а обработкой должен заниматься отдельный демон, ну или отдельный скрипт, который дергается по крону, делает какой-то объем и дохнет.